# gsutil no funciona en Suse Sles 12

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Instalé el sdk de google cloud en un Suse enterprise 12 y no me funciona el `gsutil`, cuando lo ejecuto tira los siguientes errores:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 13, in <module>
import bootstrapping
  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 46, in <module>
  from googlecloudsdk.core.updater import update_manager
  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 36, in <module>
from googlecloudsdk.core import yaml
File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/yaml.py", line 31, in <module>
from googlecloudsdk.core import yaml_location_value
File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/yaml_location_value.py", line 39, in <module>
from ruamel import yaml
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
from ruamel.yaml.main import *  # NOQA
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 6, in <module>
from typing import List, Set, Dict, Tuple, Optional, Union, BinaryIO, IO, Any  # NOQA
ImportError: No module named typing
```

Ya realicé diferentes pruebas que encontré en internet y no logro solucionarlo. Las demás herramientas de google cloud funcionan correctamente.

Comment: Actualiza el SDK de Google Cloud Platform, la versión que se liberó en diciembre tenía algunos errores con el cambio a Python 3 en las nuevas versiones ya debe estar corregido. [Aquí](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux) puedes encontrar la versión mas actualizada.

Answer (score 1):

Actualiza el SDK de Google Cloud Platform,

la versión que se liberó en diciembre tenía algunos errores con el cambio a Python 3 en las nuevas versiones ya debe estar corregido.

[Aquí](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux) puedes encontrar la versión mas actualizada.